# Laravel: how to increment login() functionality?

Tags: php, laravel

This might be simple, but I don't get it. I want that after a user logs in, program writes on a log file. So I tought it could work by extending the trait.

`LoginController` uses `AuthenticatesUsers` trait and the `login()` is there, so the first thing I did was to add my own `login()` in the LoginController, something like:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $ret = parent::login($request);

    // Do the writting to the log

    return $ret;
}
```

This didn't work... so then I turned to try a `postLogin()` function, but didn't work either, it simply didn't execute. This function is on the `LoginController`

```
public function postLogin() {
    // Do writting to the log
}
```

Which is the right way?

Comment: You're treating the trait as if it was a base class. It's not. Just rewrite the entire login function.

Comment: Sure, this thing about traits is quite new to me, I tried to apply what was in this article: https://andy-carter.com/blog/overriding-extending-a-php-trait-method

Comment: using a Trait is basically the same as copy/pasting the Trait's content in your class. To override/extend a trait's method you basically need to reimplement the function.

Comment: OK, thanks very much. Too much to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php` add the following:

```
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
      Log::info('User has logged in');
      // Do whatever else you want

    }
```

See

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating

for more information